# Allow the user to add only one type in a collection has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a animal

## app/models/animal.rb

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :tribe 
    self.inheritance_column = :race 

    def self.races
      %w(Lion WildBoar Meerkat)
    end

end
```

and 3 animals

```
class Lion < Animal; end 
class Meerkat < Animal; end 
class WildBoar < Animal; end
```

and on tribe

```
class Tribe < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :animals 
end
```

The user should be able to add only one `Lion` or one `Meerkat` or one `WildBoar`.

How i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your custom validation:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base 
  ...
  validates :only_one_type

  def only_one_type
    if self.tribe.animals.map(&:class).include?(self.class)
      errors.add(:field, "custom error")
    end
  end
end
```